# In Minecraft, is there a way you can spawn a creeper without the egg?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

After I’ve selected a world in Minecraft, I read the tips it shows me. I read one of them and it’s about a creeper. It said ‘Creepers were made from a coding bug’ does this mean I can create a creeper without the egg? I play on a Xbox 360.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Creeper):

> **The creeper was accidentally created by Notch,** the creator of
> Minecraft. While Notch was trying to create the first-ever passive
> mob, the pig, a coding mistake was made, and he accidentally swapped
> the height and lengths of the pig's build.

Instead of just discarding the bugged creation, he decided to reskin and program the glitched pig to explode, thus creating the creeper.

And, to answer your second question, you can very easily summon a creeper, by simply using the command: `/summon creeper ~ ~ ~`

Comment: Wow. Cool. Can I do that on the Xbox 360?

Comment: @DevilsbestfriendisLunar I'm not sure, as the XBox 360 doesn't allow commands. But, you can do it on Java Edition and Bedrock Edition.

Comment: I don’t have either of those.

Comment: Then you can only spawn then using the egg.

Comment: Ok. I can spread the knowledge!